# after installation of easyshutdown nothing happens when i click on it ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

i've just installed easyshutdown but when i click on it it rises up for some seconds and stops running. What is the problem. I didn't find any solution. New to ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You should launch the application from the terminal, in this way if the application still crashes you will be able to see more information about the issue in the terminal itself. After that, you could post here the description of the error and we can try together to figure out a solution.

However, you if you want to shutdown your Pc after of a certain amount of time, you can use the terminal:

```
sudo shutdown -P 60
```

"60" are minutes.

```
sudo shutdown -P 2:00
```

to shutdown at 2am, or even:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

to shutdown right now.

Comment: when i try to launch it from terminal it says the command not found. i press EasyShutdown right?

Comment: i typed in a terminal easyshutdown.py and it say access denial

Comment: when i type sudo easyshutdown.py it says command not found

Comment: Ok, I've installed the application, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 / 3.16.0-71-generic , and it works fine. So, you can try to unistall your previus version and try whit this: https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown/trunk/0.6/+download/easyshutdown_0.6_all.deb

Comment: So, you can try to uninstall your previous version and try this instead: https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown/trunk/0.6/+download/easyshutdown_0.6_all.deb                                                                                                                                  Notice that if you block the application on the launcher you can interact with it directly right clicking on it, a small menu will pop out. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i did it but stll the same...it blinks for a while (3-4 sec) and it disappears from the launcher. I also had the same problem with previous versions of ubuntu. Although with linuxmint it worked... what is going on?

Comment: Okay, let's try again to lauch the application form the terminal. 

Go to: /usr/bin

Then, type:


sudo python easyshutdown.py

I'm sure this time something will happen and if we'll be lucky the terminal will guide us to understand the problem. If it works, please post the output of the error.

Comment: it says: easyshutdown.py:48: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Unity, Gio, GObject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "easyshutdown.py", line 63, in <module>
    import pynotify
ImportError: No module named pynotify